# Solving $|x-1| + |x-2| \ge 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> Solve 
>   $$|x-1| + |x-2| \ge 4$$

My Attempt: 
I know that $|x| = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } x \ge 0  \\ -x & \text{if } x < 0 \end {cases}$. How to apply this definition to solve the problem. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider three cases:  $x\le1, 1\lt x\lt 2$, and $x\ge2$

Answer (score 3):

If $x\le 1$ then $x-2<0$ so $|x-1|+|x-2|=-(x-1)-(x-2)=-2x+3$.

If $1\lt x\lt 2$ then $|x-1|+|x-2|=x-1-(x-2)=1$.

If $x\ge2$ then $x-1\gt0$ so $|x-1|+|x-2|=(x-1)+(x-2)=2x-3$.

Thus, $|x-1|+|x-2|\ge4$ when $x\le-\frac12$ or $x\ge\frac72$.

Comment: I could not understand that how to obtained the conditions: $x \ge \frac72$ and $x\le-\frac12$

Comment: @Slowlearner:  solve $-2x+3\ge4$ when $x\le1$, and solve $2x-3\ge4$ when $x\ge2$

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Try breaking it into three parts: $x\lt1, 1\le x\le2$ and $x\gt2$.